# nlinfit Matlab function equivalent function c code

Tags: c, matlab, visual-c++, curve-fitting, data-fitting

i have a problem with curve fitting,i have to fit set of points(x and y) using this equation
a+bx^2.5+cx^3.5.Already i tried and get it from matlab curve fitting toolbox using nlinfit function.now i want to convert it in to c/c++.is there any way to convert it from matlab or else is there any library to perform in c/c++.

```
x = [0 90 180 270]';
y = [201 173 118 146]';
modelfun = @(b,x)(b(1)+ b(2).*x.^2.5+ b(3).*x.^3);
opts = statset('nlinfit');
beta0 = [0;0;0];
beta = nlinfit(x,y,modelfun,beta0,opts);
disp(beta);
 b = beta;
y1 = b(1)+ b(2).*x.^2.5 + b(3).*x.^3;
disp(y1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use `nlinfit` for this case? why not using least-squares? Make a matrix `X = [ones(numel(x),1) x(:).^2.5 x(:).^3]` and then you'll have `b = X \ y`?

Comment: visual c++ was very useful...

Comment: hi Shai...I'm not an expert in this area...can u explain how can i do that easily in c/c++...

Comment: @aranga - if you have a solution - go ahead and post it as an answer for future generations!

Comment: @shai...Ya Sure ..but i'm again struggle with matlab back slash operator..While writting code in c++ linear equation solving is a big issue...is there any idea for that...

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the very simple answer for this nlinfit....
 Matlab Code is

```
modelfun = @(b,x)(b(1)+ b(2).*x.^2.5+ b(3).*x.^3);
opts = statset('nlinfit');
beta0 = [0;0;0];
beta = nlinfit(x,y,modelfun,beta0,opts);
% % % disp(beta);
b = beta;
y1 = b(1)+ b(2).*x.^2.5 + b(3).*x.^3;
% disp(y1);
```

The equivalent function was created by this derivation

```
Ax = B;
%multiply with A' Then 
(A'*A)*x=(A'*b)
% x=(A'*A)/(A'*b)% similar to inv(A'*A)*(A'*b)
coeff1 = inv(A'*A)*(A'*B);
disp(coeff1);
```

Using those coefficients we easily find the value of Y using above equation.
Thanks to shai....